# Hyper-V default switch does not provide IP adres

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, dhcp, hyper-v, windows-11

I'm trying to setup a Hyper-V Windows VM on a Windows 11 desktop. After setting up a VM with the "quick create" utility and assigning it to the default switch it started correctly but had no internet. It looks like the default switch does not provide the VM with an IP through DHCP although I read online it should do so.

Setting a static IP fixes the issue but given the fact that the subnet changes after a reboot of the host, it's not a sustainable solution.

Connecting an external switch works but I encountered some issues with networks at my workplace so I prefer to use the default switch with it's NAT functionality.

I tried removing all the adapters, disabling the hyper V feature, rebooting and then enabling hyper V again but that didn't change anything.

I also read something about turning on Windows Sandbox in the windows features but again, no change.

I think it has something to do with the fact that the host is a company issued device where lots of features are turned off by default, but I don't know what buttons to push.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I had a similar issue.  I had not properly connected the Hyper-V Internal Switch to the Host Wireless card. The resulting VM had no internet. I deleted the machine, fixed the Internal Switch, restarted and a new VM worked perfectly.

Comment: What do you mean by "connected [...] to the Host Wireless card"? Is the default switch connected to a hardware network adapter?
And how did you fix it?

Comment: I went to Hyper-V , Switch Manager,  Default Network and ensured my Host wireless was set to the Internal Network and that VLAN ID was not checked. The internal network is just an internal NAT network and then traffic out via the host network card.

Comment: You can use whatever your host Network Adapter is.  My Laptop is only wireless.  If you have wired, use that.